# symfony on windows no route found error

Tags: php, symfony

New to PHP and Symfony. Followed the instructions outlined [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) to setup a simple helloworld project on a Windows 8.1 machine with a php version 5.6.0. However, when  hitting the webserver I get a error.

```
No route found for "GET /" 
ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception           
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: 
"No route found for "GET /"" at C:\XXX\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 2061
```

Gives me a ResourceNotFound Exception with the following trace

in app/cache/dev/appDevUrlMatcher.php at line 135   -

```
        return array (  '_controller' => 'AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction',  '_route' => 'homepage',);
    }
    throw 0 < count($allow) ? new MethodNotAllowedException(array_unique($allow)) : new ResourceNotFoundException();
}
```

}

The instructions seems UNIX Specific. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Attached is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions are not Unix specific. However, some things have changed. One thing is that the demo stuff has been removed from the "Symfony Standard Edition" and moved to a seperate application. This means that when running `symfony new ...` (or `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition`), you'll no longer have any routes available.

If you want to see a demo application, use `symfony demo`.